# Looping through multiple excel files in python using pandas

Tags: python, excel, for-loop, pandas

I know this type of question is asked all the time. But I am having trouble figuring out the best way to do this.

I wrote a script that reformats a single excel file using **pandas**. 
It works great.

Now I want to loop through **multiple** excel files, preform the same reformat, and place the newly reformatted data from each excel sheet at the bottom, one after another.

I believe the first step is to make a list of all excel files in the directory.
There are so many different ways to do this so I am having trouble finding the best way.

Below is the code I currently using to import multiple .xlsx and create a list.

```
import os
import glob

os.chdir('C:\ExcelWorkbooksFolder')
for FileList in glob.glob('*.xlsx'):
         print(FileList)
```

I am not sure if the previous glob code actually created the list that I need.

Then I have trouble understanding where to go from there.
The code below fails at `pd.ExcelFile(File)`
I beleive I am missing something....

```
# create for loop
for File in FileList:
    for x in File:
# Import the excel file and call it xlsx_file
xlsx_file = pd.ExcelFile(File)
xlsx_file
# View the excel files sheet names
xlsx_file.sheet_names
# Load the xlsx files Data sheet as a dataframe
df = xlsx_file.parse('Data',header= None)
# select important rows,
df_NoHeader = df[4:]
#then It does some more reformatting.
'
```

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Check your indentation. Whitespace and indentation matter in Python. Also you should avoid using `File` or `file` for any sort of variable names in python becuase `file` is a builtin.

Comment: Thanks! That was an issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved my problem. Instead of using the glob function I used the os.listdir to read all my excel sheets, loop through each excel file, reformat, then append the final data to the end of the table.

```
#first create empty appended_data table to store the info.
appended_data = []


for WorkingFile in os.listdir('C:\ExcelFiles'):
     if os.path.isfile(WorkingFile):

        # Import the excel file and call it xlsx_file
        xlsx_file = pd.ExcelFile(WorkingFile)
        # View the excel files sheet names
        xlsx_file.sheet_names
        # Load the xlsx files Data sheet as a dataframe
        df = xlsx_file.parse('sheet1',header= None)

        #.... do so reformating, call finished sheet reformatedDataSheet
        reformatedDataSheet
        appended_data.append(reformatedDataSheet)
appended_data = pd.concat(appended_data)
```

And thats it, it does everything I wanted.

Answer (score 3):

you need to change

```
os.chdir('C:\ExcelWorkbooksFolder')
for FileList in glob.glob('*.xlsx'):
         print(FileList)
```

to just

```
os.chdir('C:\ExcelWorkbooksFolder')
FileList = glob.glob('*.xlsx')
print(FileList)
```

Why does this fix it? `glob` returns a single list. Since you put `for FileList in glob.glob(...)`, you're going to walk that list one by one and put the result into `FileList`. At the end of your loop, `FileList` is a single filename - a single string.

When you do this code:

```
for File in FileList:
    for x in File:
```

the first line will assign `File` to the first character of the last filename (as a string). The second line will assign `x` to the first (and only) character of `File`. This is not likely to be a valid filename, so it throws an error.

Comment: Ah, yes of course. Thanks. But I guess I am still having trouble understanding the glob function. I spent more time working on the code and used os.listdir to solve my problem. Thanks for your help though!

Comment: `os.listdir` is usually more than enough (and appropriate for your case) - it lists every file in the directory, which you can filter yourself. `glob` is useful for the times when you'd something like `ls */*.xls` - i.e. you want to match wildcards, especially as part of a path. you can do that with `os.walk` but it's harder; `glob` just returns a flat list of all the matching paths, which is convenient.

Comment: Thanks, now I understand!